# Try to query and aggregate in ElasticSearch but aggregrating not working - elasticsearch.js client

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to query my dataset for two purposes:

1. Match a term (resellable = true)
2. Order the results by their price
   lowest to highest

Data set/doc is:

```
"data" : {
            "resellable" : true,
            "startingPrice" : 0,
            "id" : "4emEe_r_x5DRCc5",
            "buyNowPrice" : 0.006493, //Changes per object
            "sub_title" : "test 1",
            "title" : "test 1",
            "category" : "Education",
      
          }

//THREE OBJECTS WITH THE VALUES OF 0.006, 0.7, 1.05 FOR BUYNOWPRICE
```

I have three objects of these with different `buyNowPrice`

Query with agg is:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "data.resellable": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "aggs": {
        "lowestPrice": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "data.buyNowPrice",
                "order": {
                    "lowest_price": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "lowest_price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "data.buyNowPrice"
                    }
                },
                "lowest_price_top_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 5,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "data.buyNowPrice": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query works fine, and the results are 3 objects that have `resellable = true`

The issue is, the agg is not organizing the results based off the lowest buy now price.

Each result, the order of buyNowPrice is: 1.06, 0.006, 0.7 - which is not ordered properly.

Switching to `desc` has no affect, so I don't believe the agg is running at all?

EDIT:

Using the suggestion below my query now looks like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "data.resellable": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "aggs": {
        "lowestPrice": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "data.buyNowPrice",
                "order": {
                    "lowest_price": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "lowest_price": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "data.buyNowPrice"
                    }
                },
                "lowest_price_top_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the results of the query being:

```
  total: { value: 3, relation: 'eq' },
  max_score: 0.2876821,
  hits: [
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4emEe_r_x5DRCc5', <--- buyNowPrice of 0.006
      _score: 0.2876821,
      _source: [Object]
    },
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4ee_r_x5DRCc5', <--- buyNowPrice of 1.006
      _score: 0.18232156,
      _source: [Object]
    },
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4444_r_x5DRCc5', <--- buyNowPrice of 0.7
      _score: 0.18232156,
      _source: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT 2:

Removing the query for `resellable = true` the aggregation will sort properly and return the items in the proper order. But with the query for resellable included, it does not.

I'm assuming this has to do with the `_score` property overriding the sorting from agg? How would this be fixed

Answer (score 1):

> You can use a [bucket sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html) that is a parent pipeline
> aggregation which sorts the buckets of its parent multi-bucket
> aggregation. Zero or more sort fields may be specified together with
> the corresponding sort order.

Adding a working example (using the same index data as given in the question), search query, and search result

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "data.resellable": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "aggs": {
    "source": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.buyNowPrice"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "data.buyNowPrice",
                "data.id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "highest_price": {
          "max": {
            "field": "data.buyNowPrice"
          }
        },
        "bucket_sort_order": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": {
              "highest_price": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1.0499999523162842,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "highest_price": {
            "value": 1.0499999523162842
          },
          "latest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.08701137,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64364468",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 0.08701137,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": {
                      "id": "4emEe_r_x5DRCc5",
                      "buyNowPrice": 1.05          <-- note this
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 0.699999988079071,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "highest_price": {
            "value": 0.699999988079071
          },
          "latest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.08701137,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64364468",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 0.08701137,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": {
                      "id": "4emEe_r_x5DRCc5",
                      "buyNowPrice": 0.7         <-- note this
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 0.006000000052154064,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "highest_price": {
            "value": 0.006000000052154064
          },
          "latest": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.08701137,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64364468",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 0.08701137,
                  "_source": {
                    "data": {
                      "id": "4emEe_r_x5DRCc5",
                      "buyNowPrice": 0.006         <-- note this
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
```

**Update 1:**

**If you modify your search query as :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "data.resellable": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "lowestPrice": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "data.buyNowPrice",
        "order": {
          "lowest_price": "asc"        <-- change the order here 
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "lowest_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "data.buyNowPrice"
          }
        },
        "lowest_price_top_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running the above search query also, you will get your required results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I directly copy and paste your answer into my query I get 0 results/hits. When I change the `size: 0` to 5, I get the same hits, but again, not ordered. 

Why do you have size: 0? 

Also whats th source key for within top hits? I need the entire object returned not just the ID and buyNowPrice

Comment: @Zach `"size":0` is just meant so that I do not get hits result, and I can focus only on the aggregation part, but you can change it to `"from": 0, "size": 5,` (As you have done in your search query

Comment: I did change it to size: 5, and the results are not ordered as your results are. They are exactly the same as before, un-ordered - 1.05, 0.006, 0.7. 

Also what is the source key for within your top_hits? I would need the entire doc object returned not just the two values

Comment: @Zach can you please try the other modified query (which I updated right now), and let me know if that resolved your issue? The `_source` parameter is used to select what fields of the source are returned. I tried both the above query locally, and they are giving me the search result in proper order.

Comment: Using both your first query and the second update returns the same results: 

`total: { value: 3, relation: 'eq' },
  max_score: 0.2876821,
  hits: [
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4emEe_r_x5DRCc5', <-- 1.05
      _score: 0.2876821,
    },
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4ee_r_x5DRCc5', <-- 0.006
      _score: 0.18232156,
    },
    {
      _index: 'education',
      _type: 'listing',
      _id: '4444_r_x5DRCc5', <-- 0.7
      _score: 0.18232156,
    }
  ]
}
`

Comment: I've added an update to my original question in a nicer format. You can see my query (yours) and the results. Not sure why its not working.... changing "desc" or "asc" has no effect either.

Comment: if I remove the query in the top, for `resellable = true` then it does work perfectly and sorts based off the buyNowPrice. Any reason why this would be the case?

Comment: anyway you can provide some more help? I still cannot get the agg to apply any filtering, ive tried every combination of structure you've provided and my own, but as long as a query is included, it doesn't sort the results

Comment: @Zach that is weird :\ I tried it locally, and it's working fine. Let me go through your question and updates again, and will let you know if I found the issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223071/discussion-between-bhavya-and-zach).