# How to filter duplicates from elasticsearch query based on particular field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've checked some other answers/questions here but they are all from 2015-2017 and quite outdated for versions that are no longer supported of ElasticSearch.

I'm working with ElasticSearch js - on AWS using ElasticSearch AWS and lambda to query.

I'm trying to query my index and return 25 items - but sometimes there are duplicates with the same title field - I'd like to filter these out.

My query is:

```
query: {
            bool: {
                must: [{
                    multi_match: {
                        query: data.searchTerm,
                        fields: ["data.address",
                            "data.category",
                            "data.description^1.0",
                            "data.order_id",
                            "data.owner",
                            "data.sub_title^1.5",
                            "data.tags*^1.5",
                            "data.title^2.5",
                            "data.token_id",
                            "data.txhash",
                            "data.url",
                            "data.store.title"
                        ],
                        operator: "or",
                        lenient: "true",
                        type: 'best_fields',
                        fuzziness: "AUTO"
                    }
                }],

            }
        },
        from: Number(data.lastKey),
        size: Number(data.size)
    }
```

And I'll get 25 items back - but - some will have the same title and description - but unique ID. So I'd like to filter out the duplicates with the same titles.

How can I perform this?

I cannot use Aggs with ElasticSearch js - it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `I cannot use Aggs with ElasticSearch js - it doesn't seem to work.` why not?

Comment: Using an aggs field within ElasticSearch.js does not return any Agg data on the results.  Also I need pagination - which I believe doesn't work with aggs? But regardless if it does - I can never get an agg response on my query. After extensive discussion with this user - we came to the conclusion it was an issue with ElasticSearch.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364468/try-to-query-and-aggregate-in-elasticsearch-but-aggregrating-not-working-elast/64364606?noredirect=1#comment113816532_64364606

Comment: That's the first time I hear this... Can you show your code that does aggregations?

Comment: Its in the question linked in my last comment

Comment: I think you're mixing up two different things: the **hits** (i.e. the resulting documents of the query sorted with a top-level sort clause) with the **top hits** (i.e. the 5 top documents in each aggregated bucket)? Your query didn't have any top-level sort statement